# Find all factors(prime and composite) of a number

Tags: computer-science, complexity, factor

We can find all the prime factors using a Sieve of Erastothenes. But how do we find ALL the factors of a number?

For instance, 24 = 2x2x2x3

But the complete factor list is - 1,2,3,4,6,8,12,24.

I am thinking of pushing all the factors in a vector, then using a bit mask to get each subset. The problems with this approach are-

1. The complexity will be O(n). For n=10^10, there are 35 factors, so 2^35 sets of factors, which is 10^10.
2. Repeated subsets. As the example above, we get multiple subsets with the same factors repeated, like (22....),(2.2...),(2..2..),etc. How to remove this redundancy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most simple solution:

```
for i = 1 to sqrt(n)
   if i divides n put i and n/i into your result set 
      (make sure if i=n/i you put it only once there)
```

Complexity: O(sqrt(n))

(as long as you do not work with big numbers and can assume all basic arithmetic operations like test for divisibility as O(1).

A more sophisticated algorithm ist described [here](http://forum.projecteuler.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2556). First, find all prime factors of n including their powers dividing n (using the Sieve of Erastothenes). Then, create all combinations of those factors, as described in the blog post.

Comment: Thanks! I new there had to be some simple solution to this :)